# Автоматически подстраивающаяся ширина изображения под экран

Tags: html, css

Как сделать 3 diva

> <div class="one">one</div> <div
> class="two"><img
> src="http://cdn.demo.fabthemes.com/adament/files/2013/12/wallpaper-1136418.jpg"></div>
> <div class="three">three</div>

так чтобы, изменяя размер экрана, изображение во втором подстраивалось под экран, как в этом шаблоне: http://demo.fabthemes.com/adament/

Comment: @akasergej, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Укажите максимальную ширину и автоматическую высоту для сохранение пропорций. [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/23yppLnm/1/)

```
max-width: 100%; 
height: auto;
```